# Quick function or quick way to ignore empty value in concatenated string

Tags: php

I have this string in concatenated form:

```
$string = $firstName." | ".$middleName." | ".$lastName;
```

Now consider $middleName is empty.

**It will appear like this :**

```
John | | Doe
```

I want to ignore those variables which are empty.

**I want it like this:**

```
John Doe
```

I need a quick method for this. I can also solve this by **if else conditions** but that is not an optimum solution for this.

I need a quick method to deal these type of situations.

Any solution please ?

Comment: What is the problem in using `if else` ?

Comment: So what if only `firstName` or `lastName` is present.Also what about remaining combinations.?

Comment: I have too many cases like that in my project, so want a quick method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = implode(' | ', array_filter(array($firstName, $middleName, $lastName), 'strlen'));
```

Now you can even create a large array of parameters. All empty parameters are stripped before being concatinated. I used the pipe now, but can be anything off course.

Comment: What if firstName or lastName is empty ?

Comment: True, changed it a bit

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
$name = implode(" ", array($firstName, $middleName, $lastName));
```

Answer (score 0):

The string replace method can be specific for middle name in the following sequence

defaultName = "defaultName123";

middlename = (userInput=="")? defaultName: userInput;

Now the string will contain

| defaultname123 |

Only in the middle, you can replace that.

PS sorry there is still an if statement hiding in the ? :

Tertiary statement